# Conditional expectation.Tthe expected number of patients with advanced stage cancer, given at least one patient has early stage cancer

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

In a large population of patients, 20% have early stage cancer, 10% have advanced stage
cancer, and the other 70% do not have cancer. Six patients from this population are
randomly selected.

Calculate the expected number of selected patients with advanced stage cancer, given that
at least one of the selected patients has early stage cancer.

This is what I have so far:

Let $X$ = number of patients that has early stage cancer

Let $Y$ = number of patients that has advanced stage cancer

And I tried to use the definition of conditional expectation values

$E(Y|X \geq1) = \sum^{y=5}_{y=0} yP(Y=y|X\geq1)$

But how do I calculate $P(Y=y$ $and$ $X \geq1$)?

Or is there other better ways to solve this problem?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Easy to compute form - no sums involved: $E(Y|X\ge 1)=\frac{EY-E(Y|X=0)P(X=0)}{1-P(X=0)}$

Comment: @A.S. Could you explain how to derive the equation you wrote?

Comment: Start with $E(Y|X\ge 1)=\frac {E(Y;X\ge 1)}{P(X\ge 1)}$ and continue simplifying transformations.

Comment: @A.S. How do you get $E(Y;X \geq1)$ ?

Comment: From *definition*: $E(X|A)=\frac {E(X;A)}{P(A)}$. Finishing up the computation $E(Y|X\ge 1)=\frac {6\cdot 0.1-6\cdot\frac 1{8}(0.8)^6}{1-(0.8)^6}\approx 0.5467$ - $\approx 9\%$ less than $EY$

Comment: @A.S. I couldn't derive the equation you listed. Could you write an answer and show me your process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this as double sums, since you can calculate $P(X=x \text{ and }Y =y)$.

$$E(Y|X \geq 1) = \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum^{5}_{y=0} \sum^{6-y}_{x=1} y\,P(X=x \text{ and }Y =y) }{\displaystyle \sum^{5}_{y=0} \sum^{6-y}_{x=1} \,\,\,P(X=x \text{ and }Y =y) }$$ though you may prefer the equivalent 
$$E(Y|X \geq 1) = \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum^{6}_{x=1} \sum^{6-x}_{y=0}  y\,P(X=x \text{ and }Y =y) }{\displaystyle \sum^{6}_{x=1} P(X=x ) }$$

and in both cases the denominator is $\displaystyle P(X \geq 1)$.